# How to generate a image with text and images in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing

I have several paragraphs of text and couple of pictures between these paragraphs.

Now, I want to generate a picture using these materials, merging them vertically. But all the blocks of the text and pictures can not have bigger width than that of the generating picture, which means I have to zoom out the origin pictures, and fill each paragraph of text into a rectangle to fit the width.

Here is the tough thing:
To figure out the size of the rectangle to contain the text, I need use `Graphics.MeasureString()` method, which needs an instance of Graphics used to generate my picture(now, I'm using a blank template picture). But I do not know the exact size of this Graphics until I figure out all the sizes of rectangles and pictures.

Is there any method to get an instance of Graphics without source image?

Or is there any other method to do this work?

Comment: There aren't any appropriate static methods in `Graphics`?

Comment: It seems that Graphics.FromImage() is enough. I used to think that the instance returned by this method will be used to influence the return value of the MeasureString(). It turns out that the instance has nothing to do with MeasureString(). I get the Graphics instance from a bitmap with size(1, 1), and MeasureString() works just well! And I get another instance as the background to generate the picture \^o^/

Comment: You can also create an `Image` as `new Bitmap(width, height)` and use it as a mock object in `Graphics.FromImage()` method if you don't have an original image but you know its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this could help dude .

http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/generate-image-from-text-using-c-or-convert-text-in-to-image-using-c/

https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/654/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/388845/HOW-TO-MAKE-HIGH-QAULITY-IMAGE-WITH-TEXT-IN-Csharp

thank you

Comment: THX! The first webpage is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

For people how are intrested in a WPF solution (as asked):

```
    public static BitmapSource CreateImage(string text, double width, double heigth)
    {
        // create WPF control
        var size = new Size(width, heigth);

        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();

        var header = new TextBlock();
        header.Text = "Header";
        header.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

        var content = new TextBlock();
        content.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        content.Text = text;

        stackPanel.Children.Add(header);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(content);

        // process layouting
        stackPanel.Measure(size);
        stackPanel.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        // Render control to an image
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)stackPanel.ActualWidth, (int)stackPanel.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(stackPanel);
        return rtb;
    }
```